# Commands with hadoop work in shell but not in script

Tags: bash, shell, hadoop, command-line

I am trying to execute a very simple shell script that removes a file if it exists, and then copies a file from hdfs to the local system.

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -f /local/file
hdfs dfs -get /path/to/hdfs /local/file
```

Both commands work individually in the terminal, but fail when run as a script. Running

```
rm /local/file
```

fails with
`rm: cannot remove ‘/local/file\r’: No such file or directory`

```
hdfs dfs -get /path/to/hdfs
```

fails with `get: unexpected URISyntaxException`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: That error message suggests your script file is in DOS/Windows format; see [Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)

Comment: You're right, dos2unix fixed it. Thank you!